# How would you display an asterisk beside an above average number in an array?

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a list of numbers so that it will show up like this (with an asterisk beside above average numbers):

```
53
56
68
78*
79*
80*
89*
90*
100*
```

I've tried this(scores is my array of numbers):

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] > average) {
        System.out.println(scores[i] + "*");
    }
}
```

And this:

```
for (double element : scores) {
    int aboveAvg = 0;
    for (int i = 0, i <scores.length; i++){
        if (scores[i] > average) {
            aboveAvg++;
            System.out.println(element + "*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calculating the average? Compiling this code just gives a compiler error "*average* not found" (and "*scores* not found", but I can guess how that was defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] pArgs) {
        List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        numList.add(53);
        numList.add(100);
        numList.add(56);
        numList.add(90);
        numList.add(68);
        numList.add(89);
        numList.add(78);
        numList.add(89);
        numList.add(80);

        int sum = 0, average = 0;
        for (Integer n : numList) {
            sum += n;
        }
        average = sum / numList.size();
        System.out.println("Average: " + average);

        Collections.sort(numList);
        for (Integer n : numList) {
            if (n > average) {
                System.out.println(n + "*");
            } else {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Average: 78
53
56
68
78
80*
89*
89*
90*
100*
```